# Issues with installUtill

Tags: visual-studio-2010, c#-4.0, windows-installer

We are migrating our applications from 32 bit to 64 bit. And also .net framework 3.5 to 4.0.+Visual Studio 2008 to Visual Studio 2010

Aspart of migration we created all msi's in 64 bit with visul studio 2010. we had a problem while installing them.

we are getting System.BadImage error for the msi's which are having some customaction condigured in depolyment project. Due to this error installation rolled backed.

**Root Casue Identified:**

For doing customaction we have projects with installer classes While installing those using msi we caught that error.

When ever we get that error.We just tried installing that .exe manually using 64 bit visual studio commandLine with installUtil.exe command. it successfully installed.

But when we are using 32 bit visual studio commandLine with installUtil.exe, we end up with the same error.

So problem is when ever we are using msi its picking the 32 bit installUtil.exe eventough the msi is 64 bit which is causing the problem.

**Tried Solutions:**

1.Tried debugging the installer class using Debugger.Launch(). But before hitting the point we end up with error.

2.Try to edit the Database table of msi with orca editor to pick the correct version of installUtil.exe. But failed with other error.

**Question:**

1.How can we modify our solutions to pick the 64 bit installUtil.exe?(if we can do this)

Answer (score 2):

This might be the issue:

http://blogs.msdn.com/b/heaths/archive/2006/02/01/64-bit-managed-custom-actions-with-visual-studio.aspx

You don't need installer classes. Visual Studio setups to generate MSI files are not in newer versions of VS, so you should use a tool that uses the standard methods of installing services, ServiceInstall and ServiceControl being the underlying tables in the MSI file.

Answer (score 2):

Rule #1: Don't reinvent the wheel. Avoid CA's wherever possible.(See PhilDW's answer)

Rule #2: When you really must use a managed custom action don't use InstallUtil.  Use Windows Installer XML (WiX) Deployment Tools Foundation (DTF) instead.

Rule #3: Write custom actions that follow MSI's transactional model (Install, Rollback, Commit) whenever possible.

Rule #4: Write data driven, declarative (custom tables) custom actions whenever possible.

Rule #5: Honor the security model of MSI ( custom actions that change data must be deferred in the system context )

Rule #6: Test the !@Q%Q! out of your CA's.  Make sure that install, uninstall, reinstall, cancel (rollback ) and upgrade (and upgrade rollback), repair and silent installs all work as expected.  Hint:  Rule #1 exists because you get this for free when you don't write custom actions.

Reference:
[Deployment Tools Foundation (DTF) Managed Custom Actions](http://blog.deploymentengineering.com/2008/05/deployment-tools-foundation-dtf-custom.html)